# .htaccess RewriteRule not working, bad flag delimiters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, pretty-urls

My site previously uses URL's like this: `/folder/page`

Previously, you could prepend 'panel' in the URL to edit the current page: `/panel/folder/page`

We upgraded our CMS, and the new URL to edit the page is in this format: `/panel/#/pages/show/folder/page`

I am trying to add a rewrite rule so that we can still use the old way, but can't get it to work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/panel/#/
RewriteRule /panel(.*) /panel/#/pages/show/$1
```

Is there a way to do this? A 301 redirect should work too, I think.

Edit: here is my existing .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

# make panel links work
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^panel/(.*) panel/index.php [L]

# make site links work
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php [L]
```

Comment: You can't parse or rewrite hashtag since it's client side only. Anyway, you can redirect with a hashtag. You can replace your two lines by this rule: `RewriteRule ^panel/(.+)$ /panel/#/pages/show/$1 [R=301,L,NE]`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work though, it breaks some stuff on the client side.

Comment: If it is redirecting to the path that the CMS needs, how can it break anything?

Comment: `RewriteRule "^/?panel/([^\#]+)$" "/panel/#/pages/show/$1" [R=301,L,NE]` wo RewriteCond

Comment: @Deadooshka that causes a redirect loop

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/panel/#/`; The `%{REQUEST_URI}` never receives URLs with `#` anchors.

Comment: need to track a real URL-string that RewriteRule gets http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging

Answer (score 0):

Since "panel" is already used, I ended up using this redirect rule:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /admin(.*) /panel/#/pages/show/$1
```